# Webpack 5 - PurgeCss - Not a Constructor Error

Tags: webpack

**Webpack 5, PurgeCss, Purgecss-webpack-plugin,**

Hi there,
I created a project using **Webpack 5** to handle the **Scss => CSS** conversion plus a lot more.
I've gotten everything to work but the **PurgeCss**.
I keep getting the error **PurgeCss is not a constructor** when I run Webpack.
Funny enough this used to work but ever since I updated the package.json file to get rid of vulnerabilities and now it crashes.
[The full code can be found on the GitHub repo.](https://github.com/denOldTimer/qs-dc-lemp-mvc-webpack-base).
If someone can tell me why, I would appreciate it, Thanks.

```js
const path = require("path");
// const glob = require("glob");
const _MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const _StyleLintPlugin = require("stylelint-webpack-plugin");
const _ESLintPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const _CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
// const { _PurgeCSSPlugin } = require("purgecss-webpack-plugin");

// const PATHS = {
//   src: path.join(__dirname, "../src"),
// };
// const PurgecssPlugin = new _PurgeCSSPlugin({
//   paths: glob.sync(`${PATHS.src}/**/*`),
// });

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = new _MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: "[name].css",
  chunkFilename: "[id].css",
});

const ESLintPlugin = new _ESLintPlugin({
  overrideConfigFile: path.resolve(__dirname, ".eslintrc"),
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/js"),
  files: "**/*.js",
});

const StyleLintPlugin = new _StyleLintPlugin({
  configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "stylelint.config.js"),
  //configBasedir: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/"),
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/scss"),
  files: "**/*.scss",
  syntax: "scss",
});

/**
 * If getting an error during npm start or watch it's
 * most posable because the src/fonts or src/img folders are empty
 */
const CopyPlugin = new _CopyPlugin({
  patterns: [
    {
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/img/"),
      to: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../project/public/img/"),
    },
    {
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/fonts/"),
      to: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../project/public/fonts/"),
    },
    {
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.php"),
      to: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../project/public/index.php"),
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = {
  CleanWebpackPlugin: new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  MiniCssExtractPlugin: MiniCssExtractPlugin,
  // PurgecssPlugin: PurgecssPlugin,
  ESLintPlugin: ESLintPlugin,
  StyleLintPlugin: StyleLintPlugin,
  CopyPlugin: CopyPlugin,
};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As noted in https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/issues/994

Updating the import to the exact case

```js
const { PurgeCSSPlugin } = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');
```

seems to fix it!

Comment: The suggested fix works now, but had a typo forgot to remove the underscore

Answer (score 2):

So apparently this is a webpack-purgecss-plugin 5.0 issue since webpack 5.0
So I downgraded the plugin to 4.1.3 and it works again.